# Is there any way to setup multiple ssl sites on one amazon instance(EC2)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I've made two IPs on 1 instance so I currently have two sites like http://example.com and http://example1.com
however the problem is the only one site has ssl setup (https://example.com)
so, when I try to connect to https://example1.com, it's automatically redirect to https://example.com.
I want to make 2 different sites with ssl. If you know any answers, please help me.

Comment: 2 Ip's act as primary & secoundary, you need to use vertual host entry and separate certs / wild-card cert if you have subdomain arch. ref : https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/apache-multiple-ssl-certificates-using-sni.htm

Comment: or use ELB to terminate SSL connection.

Comment: @RodrigoM Thank you soooo much. It perfectly worked!